# Child bones creating at 3d cursor instead of at parent

Tags: rigging, bones

I'm an experienced 3DSMax user learning Blender. So, for rigging, I create a bone, and then Shift+A to extrude a child from that bone and pull it to where I want the next joint. Up until now that's been working fine, but suddenly it's behaving differently- now when I Shift+A it places a bone at the 3D cursor, instead of at the tail of the parent bone. I'm sure I must've toggled something on or off accidentally for this to have happened, does anyone know what it might be...?

Comment: Try going into edit mode, selecting the armature's tail, press E to extract, then ESC so you can drag the extruded tail out from the armature.

Comment: shift A should not extrude, shift A places a bone where the 3D cursor is. To create a bone at the top of another bone use E (extrude). Also, extrude will make the new bone a child of the previous one.

Comment: Gah, of course! It was Shift+E. I just got my hotkeys mixed up. Thanks guys.